# odd text display C#

Tags: c#, forms, iteration

I have the following code in a windows form:

```
for (int i = 1; (i <= 10); i++)
{
    if ((worker.CancellationPending == true))
    {
        e.Cancel = true;
        break;
    }
    else
    {                 
        try
        {                     
            string message = "";
            string m = "";
            textBox2.Text = "";
            int count = 0;

            while (TestConnection(client))
            {
                char tt = ' ';                    

                try
                {
                    tt = Convert.ToChar(sr.Read());

                    if (count < 4)
                    {
                        message = tt.ToString();
                        m += message;
                        count += 1;
                    }
                    else if (count >= 4)
                    {
                        this.Invoke(new BindTextBoxControl(UpdateTextbox), new object[] {m + "\r\n"});
                        textBox2.Text = m + "\r\n";
                        m = "";
                        count = 0;
                    }
                }
                catch (OverflowException)
                {
                    m += "";
                }
            }
         }
         catch (Exception g)
         {
             string error = "An error occurred: '{0}'" + g;
         }
```

this gets a continuous stream of data from a StreamReader and then displays the data (4 character string). It is supposed to replace the current string shown with a new one(if the string is rrrr and then i receive tttt it shows tttt) but what it does is remove the first letter of the current string and add the next revived letter (have rrrr get tttt shows rrrt then rrtt and so forth).

how do i get this to work properly?

EDIT:

```
private void UpdateTextbox(string _Text)
        {
            textBox1.Text = _Text;
        }

delegate void BindTextBoxControl(string text);
```

Nothing special about these.

Comment: Can you share the code of `UpdateTextbox` and `BindTextBoxControl` also?

Comment: added the requested info.